# Facebook banner ads cause app crashed

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, android-banner

I've added a Facebook banner ad in my android app.The banner will display normally. Sometimes ad requests cause the app to crash. The error info is: ad is not already....
How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in the 4.4.1 release (see changelog here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x)